# Where should I add DKIM valid record and SPF valid record for verifying domains in mandrill

Tags: mandrill

I have followed mandrill guide to convert mandrill as mailChimp add-on. While doing this process, we need to verify the sending domains. To do that, we should create SPF and DKIM records. Could you please anyone guide me to add these records in DNS providers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this record in DNS Zone record.
**Step 1:** Login to your Domain purchase account
**Step 2:** Click on Edit DNS Zone record
**Step 3:** Add mandrill._domainkey as you create for a subdomain
**Step 4:** In Type the default option will be **A** change it to **TXT** 
**Step 5:** In Data paste your text content
**Step 6:** Save the content
this will solve your issue.